# Attenuate 750 mV differential speaker level out to 636 mV line level in

Tags: arduino, voltage, audio, attenuator

I am developing an Arduino project using an [RN52](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/RN52-Bluetooth-Audio-Module-DS70005120B.pdf) Bluetooth shield and an [Si4713](https://www.skyworksinc.com/-/media/Skyworks/SL/documents/public/data-sheets/Si4712-13-B30.pdf) FM transceiver.

The RN52 has differential (speaker L+ & L-, R+ & R-) speaker level output (750 mV Vpk) and the Si4713 has LIN/RIN (636 mV max).

So I need:

1. a circuit to sum balanced speaker level output to line level input
2. a circuit to attenuate summed speaker down to 636 mV - preferably to 525 mV so I can take advantage of the dynamic TX on the Si4713.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please provide data sheet links for both devices.

Comment: Si4713 datasheet: https://www.skyworksinc.com/-/media/Skyworks/SL/documents/public/data-sheets/Si4712-13-B30.pdf

Comment: RN-52 data sheet: https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/RN52-Bluetooth-Audio-Module-DS70005120B.pdf

Comment: Sound volume, i.e., voltage level, varies with time. Do you need an attenuator,  or a *limiter*? Two diodes, back-to-back, might be sufficient: https://lambdageeks.com/diode-voltage-drop/

Comment: An opamp and a few resistors?

Comment: The RN_52 speaker output is 750 mV rms full scale swing (differential), which can drive 2 speakers @  8 ohm load (and 500 pF capacitance load). The analog gain is 0 to -21 dB.

Comment: the Si4713 has a max line in voltage of 636 mV.